# Map markers in MapView - scale them in the zoom animation

Tags: android, google-maps

When the user zooms my MapView, I want the my markers (OverlayItems) to zoom too (during the animation!). After the animation they would return to normal size. This is how markers behave in Google Maps. In MapView, OverlayItems in ItemizedOverlay have always the same size even during the zoom animaion, which looks odd.

Answer (score -1):

how about manually rescaling the marker on zoom in/out event?